# Alternative to SuperShuttle at LAX?

Tags: airport-transfer, transportation, lax

It has recently been announce that the [SuperShuttle](https://www.supershuttle.com) is totally closing down at LAX (and everywhere else). ([SuperShuttle is going out of business. Its last rides are Dec. 31](https://www.latimes.com/travel/story/2019-12-12/supershuttle-says-it-will-stop-service-to-lax))

This is a service that I use a lot when I visit LA.  I saw this announcement soon after booking my next trip in January.

Aside from things like Uber, what other alternatives are there for transportation from LAX directly to a residential address, or is the Uber model the only thing left that fulfills the SuperShuttle role?

Comment: Uber’s goal has been to run taxis, busses,  and shuttles out of business so that Uber can them raise prices. They’re succeeding.

Comment: For anyone reading in 2021: SuperShuttle was bought out by another company at one point, and continues to operate, but only in name (they now contract with other existing local shuttle companies instead of operating their own).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search for "shuttle to LAX" revealed:

- [Shuttle to Lax](https://www.shuttletolax.com/#/search)
- [Prime Time Shuttle](https://www.primetimeshuttle.com/)
- [24-7 Ride](https://247ride.com/shuttles/shuttle-to-lax/)
- [Karmel Shuttle](https://www.karmel.com/shuttle-to-lax)

I stopped copying-and-pasting after the first page. May well be others.

Comment: Prime Time Shuttle seems to say to use Opoli at LAX, and Opoli seems to be a service similar to Uber and Lyft. Shuttle to LAX seems to have the exact same instructions and phone numbers for LAX pickup as Prime Time Shuttle.

Comment: @user102008 I'm not at all surprised that some of the listings are multiple and self-referencing. Still, two of the four I found might bear fruit for the OP or others.