# LAX to Anaheim Transfer?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, lax, shared-taxis

I need to get from LAX to Anaheim on a Saturday afternoon. My hotel is located in Anaheim, south of the [S Harbor Blvd-Orangewood Ave crossroads](https://goo.gl/maps/fDhxeK81sNosR3m5A), so getting anywhere in that vicinity would be best. I would also be fine getting to the Convention Center and having to walk for, say, 30 minutes.
I initially wanted to use SuperShuttle (as recommended [here](https://insideoursuitcase.com/shuttle-from-lax-to-anaheim/) and on [TravelSE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/457/lax-to-anaheim-how-much-slower-is-the-super-shuttle-than-a-cab)) but just found out they [went out of business](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151316/alternative-to-supershuttle-at-lax). Most shuttle services I found cost around $100, one cost $70.

Is there **any cheaper option** (SuperShuttle used to cost about $20)? **I am fine with public transport** if available.

Edit: I do not consider this a duplicate of [Alternative to SuperShuttle at LAX?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/151316/alternative-to-supershuttle-at-lax) because I specifically ask for cheaper alternatives than current shuttle services (i.e., < $80) including public transport.

Comment: An Uber from Anaheim to the beach (similar distance) costs about $70. Sounds like the rate might be reasonable unless you want shared or public transport.

Comment: SuperShuttle still technically exists; another company bought out the brand name and they now contract their services to other companies, which in the case of LAX, are Karmel and Prime Time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cheapest, but also probably most timeconsuming option seems to be a combination of Flyaway bus and Metrolink:

Take the Flyaway bus to Union station (bus runs approx. every 30 minutes), info at https://www.flylax.com/flyaway-bus/union-station. One way fare for that part is $9.75.

Then take Metrolink Orange County line from Union Station to Orange (timetable: https://metrolinktrains.com/globalassets/rider-info/rail2rail_timetable_oceanside_04.03.17.pdf), fare for this part is $9. Note, depending on the exact time of the day, you might have to use a different rail line here, e.g. Pacific Surfliner or Metrolink Perris Valley Line.

From Orange rail station take bus line 54 to Chapman-West, from there it's around a half mile walk (a bit more than 10 minutes) to your destination. Fare for this part should be $1.75, which brings it to a total of $20.50. Total travel time according to Google Maps around 2.5 hours.

Link to Google Maps route: https://goo.gl/maps/wAhiD2hCt3Uk3Vyr6

Comment: Thanks! I did end up using the train to Anaheim (which I can recommend). One thing to note here is that Metrolink is significantly cheaper than Pacific Surfliner (8.75$ vs. 16$ LAX-ANA).

Answer (score 6):

A cheaper option is to take the LA Metro from LAX and transfer onto a local bus to Anaheim.

From the LAX terminals, you can take the free shuttle bus to the Aviation/LAX LA Metro station. From there, it costs $1.75 for a single ride on the LA Metro (plus $2 to purchase a TAP card). Ride the C Line (Green Line) to the eastern terminus at Norwalk. From there, take LA bus route 460 with a free transfer, which terminates at the Disneyland local bus stop.

In your specific case, to get to your hotel at Harbor Blvd. and Orangewood Ave., you can then take Orange County bus route 43 from Disneyland, which has a stop at that intersection. The fare for OCTA bus routes is $2, and they do not accept TAP cards, so you must either pay in cash or buy a ticket from the OCTA app. Several other OCTA bus routes stop at the Disneyland bus stop, making it easy to travel elsewhere in Anaheim.

To summarize, you can get to your hotel in Anaheim from LAX for a total of $5.75 maximum ($2 TAP card purchase, $1.75 LA Metro fare, free transfer to LA buses, and $2 Orange County bus fare). The return journey would be $3.75 since you already have a TAP card.